# compilererror, matrix expected vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Im working on a vba program. When I want to use an array I get the compileerror: matrix expected.

In a for loop Im using this code

```
 N = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AS").Range("$O$2")
 ReDim Powerarray(0 To N) As Double
 Powerarray(0) = 7
 ... 
 Watt = Powerarray(w)
```

and somewhere else i fill up the array with this code:

```
 Dim Watt As Double     
 Dim Powerarray As Double
 Watt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AS").Range("O6").value  'w is an integer
 w = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AS").Range("O2").value - 3
 ...

 Powerarray(w) = Watt
```

Any idea what is causing the problem?

Comment: By the way, the codes are in 2 different sub's, so in the first sub i fill the array, and in the second sub i use the array

Comment: Which line errors? Why do you assign an array element and then a cell value to Watt?

Comment: Where the error exactly? Also PowerArray is array or double?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dim Powerarray As Double is not array, but  variable.

If you want to use array in seperate sub. use Public variable.

```
Public Powerarray() As Double
Sub test1()
 N = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AS").Range("$O$2")
 ReDim Powerarray(0 To N) As Double
 Powerarray(0) = 7
 ...
 Watt = Powerarray(w)

End Sub
Sub test2()
Dim Watt As Double
'Dim Powerarray As Double '<~~ this is not needed.
 Watt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AS").Range("O6").Value  'w is an integer
 w = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AS").Range("O2").Value - 3
 ...

 Powerarray(w) = Watt
End Sub
```